# AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'user_options'

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am trying to setup this basic example from the following doc:

> http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/celery/

But so far I keep getting the below error:

> AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'user_options'

I am using celery 3.1.15.

```
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

Example:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379'
)
celery = make_celery(app)


@celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 769, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 305, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 473, in setup_app_from_commandline
    user_preload = tuple(self.app.user_options['preload'] or ())
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'user_options'
```

Comment: Please show us the *full* traceback of the error.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to add that.

Comment: What command line did you use to run Celery? How did you configure Celery *itself*? You only showed us the Flask integration side.

Comment: so I am using "celery -A <my_application> worker" to run the celery.

Comment: I am not configuring anything on celery side.I am just following that documentation directly.

Comment: Can you please show us pip free?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help. Fixed the issue. I was running the celery worker incorrectly.Silly mistake on my side.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The Flask Celery Based Background Tasks page (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/celery/) suggests this to start celery:

`celery -A your_application worker`

> The your_application string has to point to your application’s package or module that creates the celery object.

Assuming the code resides in application.py, explicitly pointing to the celery object (*not just the module name*) avoided the error:

`celery -A application.celery worker`

Comment: I've been running into a number of issues of this kind.  Celery's a bit magical for my tastes.

Comment: I got same problem today... My issue was `app = Flask(__name__)` because it clash with celery internal `self.app`. So you just need to rename `app = Flask(__name__)` to "application" or something else to avoid this traceback

Comment: This worked for me ️

Comment: I love Celery but the docs leave MUCH to be desired. I suppose they only cater to veteran network and web programmers... Kinda hostile toward newbs.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
celery -A my_app_module_name.celery worker
```

Comment: For me as well. I use `celery 4.3.0 (rhubarb)`

Answer (score 0):

rename app flask_app
It will work

Comment: This is irrelevant. The OP is not struggling with any NameError and your answer is quite vague how it could solve the problem (which it seems it doesn't anyway).

Comment: @Reti43 if the file name is app.py, then `app = Flask(__name__)` will have a conflict. To resolve this, he suggested renaming the app to flask_app. I agree that @nhywieza did not give the proper context.

Answer (score -4):

like this:

```
celery -A your_application worker
```

where your_application stands:

```
your_application = Flask(\__name\__)
```

the python file name: **your_application**.py, it will work

By the way, celery v4 is unsupported in Windows