# celery start causes TypeError("unhashable type: 'list'",)

Tags: python, flask, celery, flask-socketio

I am following the documentation for http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/

and am getting the following error.

```
$ python ./venv/bin/celery -A app.ctasks worker -c 8 -l INFO
[2018-04-19 08:45:03,623: ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: TypeError("unhashable type: 'list'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/andy.terhune/PycharmProjects/flask_socketio_saml/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 323, in __get__
return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'backend'
```

I have checked make_celery's line and backend and broker are strings with the correct data.

```
celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'], broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
```

My celery setup is the following:

`cinit.py`

```
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'], broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    taskbase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(taskbase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return taskbase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask,
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
async_mode = None

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)
...
from app import views, socks, saml, helper, cinit
celery = cinit.make_celery(app)
from app import ctasks
```

I have tried to start celery several different ways to no avail.

`python ./venv/bin/celery -A app.ctasks worker -c 8 -l INFO`

causes:

`Unrecoverable error: TypeError("unhashable type: 'list'",)`

`python ./venv/bin/celery -A app worker -c 8 -l INFO`

causes:

`AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'user_options'`
which I found a similar article here: [AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'user_options'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884951/attributeerror-flask-object-has-no-attribute-user-options)

and

`python ./venv/bin/celery -A app.cinit worker -c 8 -l INFO`

causes:

`AttributeError: module 'app.cinit' has no attribute 'celery'`
which I would expect because I never set or import celery into cinit.py.

Comment: Is that the complete stack trace of the error? Seems you missed to include some information there.

Answer (score -1):

had similar issue 
had to clear my backend server in order to get things working again
in my case it is redis:

```
redis-cli FLUSHALL
```